# How to change/increment the date for all commits in git history?

Tags: git, date, commit

I messed up with my computer's date and now I'd like to **fast forward 2 days** in all commits I've done in a given project.
Since I've created this project while in the wrong date, I don't need to choose them separately - so applying this change to all of them would work.
How can I make it happen?

**Current**:

```
commit 11b8e6006f3a316430813e9c12c8dc7c0dcb4b2f
Author: Me <myemail@emailcom>
Date:   Sun Jul 11 20:14:04 2021 -0200

    refac: title component

commit 10b8e6006f3a316430813e9c12c8dc7c0dcb4b2d
Author: Me <myemail@emailcom>
Date:   Sun Jul 11 18:43:03 2021 -0200

    fix: update image
```

**Expected**:

```
commit 11b8e6006f3a316430813e9c12c8dc7c0dcb4b2f
Author: Me <myemail@emailcom>
Date:   Tue Jul 13 20:14:04 2021 -0200

    refac: title component

commit 10b8e6006f3a316430813e9c12c8dc7c0dcb4b2d
Author: Me <myemail@emailcom>
Date:   Tue Jul 13 18:43:03 2021 -0200

    fix: update image
```

(for all commits)

Comment: You'll need to replace the old (and incorrect) commits with new-and-improved (corrected) commits, and stop using the old commits. You must do this in every copy of the repository (well, every copy of those commits), which is often very hard *unless* there's only one copy; then it's pretty easy. The mechanics for *how* to do this are "use `git filter-branch`". But: why do you care? Dates are easily faked so no one should rely on them anyway.